# Can't figure out why multi-precision calculation doesn't work for me using boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

First I tried using GMP because boost documentation says it is faster but the gmp.h file was missing from boost library so I had to install GMP library and copy the gmp.h. After doing so I was getting external symbol Error when using mpz_int.
So I decided to try cpp_int, copied the example from boost documentation and it worked. this is what I tried:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;

   int128_t v = 1;

   // Do some fixed precision arithmetic:
   for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 20; ++i)
      v *= i;

   std::cout << v << std::endl; // prints 20!

   // Repeat at arbitrary precision:
   cpp_int u = 1;
   for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
      u *= i;

   std::cout << u << std::endl; // prints 100!

   return 0;
}
```

So then I created a factorial function in a Math class but now every time i use a variable from cpp_int library I receive that error:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z)

Now every time I try to assign a new value to cpp_int variable I get that error, the weird thing is that the example worked and now the same example doesn't work for this project, but if I create a new project and use the same boost lib it works again.

Comment: *After doing so I was getting external symbol Error when using mpz_int. So I decided to try cpp_int, copied the example from boost documentation and it worked. this is what I tried:* -- You really shouldn't be switching out libraries like this unless you fully know what you're doing.  Trial and error isn't the place when you're trying to build an application.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to calculate big numbers, It wasn't in an application that I am working on, I created a new project for that , trial and error is the way to learn new things isn't it?

Comment: Switching libraries and luckily getting something to work does not teach you **why** the other library or libraries did not work.  If you do any sort of development under Windows, and faced with a third-party library issue, it is imperative you know what to do when this happens again.  The answer given by shrike has given some insight into why the issue exists.

Comment: I did not mention that but, I did post a question about the previous library that did not work for me and decided to try a different approach while I am waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that one of the library you are using (probably the cpp_int library) wants to link with the **Debug** version of the Visual Studio runtime library. (Symbol `__CrtDbgReportW` is defined in the **Debug** version of the VS runtime library only.)

Make sure you compile your code for the appropriate target (Debug/Release), the third party libraries you are using are compiled for the same target, and that you link with the corresponding runtime library.

EDIT (after the comments you added earlier) :

Make sure you compile your code for the **Static** **Debug** version of the VC runtime library (aka `libcpmtd.lib`) :

In Visual Studio, open the Project Properties dialog and, in `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation`, field `Runtime Library`, set to : `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.

Note that any other library you link to your build must have the same setting.

Comment: How do I make sure that the third party libraries are compiled for the Debug target? And I am only using the header files from boost library, do I use different headers for different runtimes?

Comment: You use the same headers for all libraries.  Header files do not usually have anything to do with what library you link to.  The only exception to this is if your header files have `#pragma comment (lib,"somelib")` specified, giving the linker instructions on which library to use.  I believe this is how boost does things (for example, if you don't specify any library, and you're using one of boost's classes that are not header-only classes, then the linker will state what library you're missing -- but this is only available via the special `#pragma` I mentioned).

Comment: The linker doesn't give me anything about missing libraries so I am using header-only classes, And I'm sure I compile my code for the appropriate target, otherwise I can't compile because when I include headers with the wrong target compiler can't find the header file.

Comment: The full line of the only error I'm getting is :1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z). Does it mean I'm missing libcpmtd.lib? If yes how is it possible that the same project with the sam example compiled correctly and now id doesn't? I did not change anything that could unlink that library.

Comment: @user3196144 : are you building your application for Release or Debug target ?

Comment: I'm building for Debug target

Comment: @user3196144 : seems you have a mess with the VC runtime library; see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that was it , Thank you very much.